# click function doesnot work after auto page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, page-refresh

I am refreshing my page every 25 seconds using Javascript.But another Javascript for click function works fine before page refresh whereas after page refresh it doesnot work.

HTML:

```
 <div id="refreshOnline">
    <div id="refreshData">
    //Set of Functions
     <a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/startgame.php?gname='.$key['gameName'].'&player='.$_SESSION["uname"].'&type=t20" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm popup-game" id="popup-game" >Play Now!</a>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Javascript:

```
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
   //Script to refresh Div
   function show_data()
   {
    $('#refreshOnline').load('main.php #refreshData');
   }
    setInterval('show_data()', 25000);

   //Script to oprn link in new window
    $('#popup-game').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Working");
     window.open($(this).attr("href"), "popupWindow","width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes");
   });
</script>
```

Before refresh, link opens in new window whereas after execution of refresh script, link opens in new tab instead of new window.

Comment: Javascript can't control whether `window.open()` opens a window or a tab. I'm not sure why it's inconsistent.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 2):

The code:

```
$('#popup-game').click(...
```

binds a click handler to the `#popup-game` element that exists at the moment that code runs. If that element is a child of `#refreshOnline` it will be replaced when you refresh `#refreshOnline` and so the new version of that element will not have a click bound. You can use a delegated event handler instead:

```
$('#refreshOnline').on('click', '#popup-game', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("Working");
  window.open($(this).attr("href"), "popupWindow","width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes");
});
```

This actually binds the handler to `#refreshOnline`, but when a click occurs jQuery automatically checks if it was on a child element that matches the selector in the second parameter and only calls your function if it does.

For more information see [the `.on()` doco](http://api.jquery.com/on).

Comment: I used specified code but my link goes to new tab before refresh

Answer (score 0):

This is because the click handler is not assigned to the new content. Set them again after you have changed the content like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//Script to refresh Div
function show_data()
{
  $('#refreshOnline').load('main.php #refreshData');
  setClickers();
}

function setClickers(){
  //Script to oprn link in new window
  $('#popup-game').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Working");
    window.open($(this).attr("href"), "popupWindow","width=600,height=600,scrollbars=yes");
  });
}

$(function(){
  setClickers();
  setInterval('show_data()', 25000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Or just use event delegation with `.on()`.

Comment: @Terwanerik But function setClickers() will not be called in <a> tag right?

Comment: No only in show_data(), but you should try to use the `on()` delegate first, i had some issues with that in combination with AJAX hence my answer

Comment: I used the above code. But still the problem is same

Answer (score 0):

You should register the click event every time you refresh the content of the div.